# Why lambda x: all(x[x == 0]) doesn't work as expected in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

So I have a dataframe, sample of which is as below:

```
    ID  Date        Week_1  Week_2  Week_3  Week_4  Week_5  Week_6  Week_7  Week_8  Week_9
0   A   2022-01-01  0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       1
1   A   2022-01-02  0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       1
2   B   2022-01-01  0       0       0       0       0       1       1       1       1
3   A   2022-02-03  0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       1
4   B   2022-01-04  0       0       0       0       0       1       1       1       1
5   B   2022-01-15  0       0       0       0       0       1       1       1       1
6   C   2022-01-02  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1
7   C   2022-01-02  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1
8   D   2022-01-02  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1
9   D   2022-01-01  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1
10  E   2022-03-01  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

I get expected output when I try to find out if any of `Week_` columns is `1` I use:

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x : any(x[x == 1]), axis = 1), :]
```

But when I try to find out if not even a single `1` is present across all columns, i.e. if all values in `Week_` columns are `0`s using:

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x : all(x[x == 0]), axis = 1), :]
```

I even tried below codes and still don't get the expected result.

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x : all(x[x != 1]), axis = 1), :]
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x : all(x[x < 1]), axis = 1), :]
```

I get an empty result set but I should be getting row 10 with `ID` `E`.

Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `x` to `row` for better meaning

```py
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda row: all(row[row == 0]), axis = 1), :]
```

`row == 0` will return True if value is `0`. So `row[row == 0]` will only select `0`. `all` on `0` array will return False in any case.

In fact, `row == 0` already returns boolean Series, you can use

```py
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda row: row.eq(0).all(), axis = 1), :]
```

Personally speaking, I would write as

```py
m = df.filter(like='Week').eq(0).all(axis=1)
out = df[m]
```

```
print(out)

   ID        Date  Week_1  Week_2  Week_3  Week_4  Week_5  Week_6  Week_7  Week_8  Week_9
10  E  2022-03-01       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Shouldn't `row[row ==0]` return `True` instead of `0` ? If all of `row[row==0]` is `True` then so should be the result?

Comment: @KarthikS `row` is a DataFrame row here, for example `0   A   2022-01-01  0       0       0       1       0       0       0       1       1` is the first row. `row == 0` returns boolean Series and `row[row == 0]` does boolean indexing on `row`.

Comment: Sorry for the follow up, I am still trying to understand. I tried: `all([0 == 0, 0 == 0, 0 == 0])` and the result was `True`, could you please tell me how `row[row==0]` is different?

Comment: @KarthikS You can use `print(row[row==0])` to see what it returns. You need to do boolean indexing in the next step.

Comment: @KarthikS Your `all([0 == 0, 0 == 0, 0 == 0])` is `all(row == 0)` not `all(row[row == 0])`.